# Android: is it possible to query mbtiles database in android platform

Tags: android, osmdroid, mbtiles

I use the vector mbtiles database in my Android project.

It contains some list of Features.
I use this mbtiles as a data source for Vector Layer at Mapbox.
At the same time I need to get this list of Features without using Mapbox.

Is it possible to query the data from this vector mbtiles database?

Comment: It might be easier to find a way to read your mbtiles and convert them to one big geojson for referencing the features